# Why does a string in Python resolve to True?

Tags: python, if-statement

The title might need some re-wording, but here's my question:

The code below ends up False, and thus prints nothing. Changing to `d = 1<10` ends up True.

```
c = "text"
d = 1>10

if d:
    print c
```

Simple enough. But now if I change `d = "more text"` the if statement also prints c. Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's how python strings are defined. When you try to evaluate them as a boolean, only the empty string returns `False`. All other strings return `True`.

```
>>> bool('not an empty string')
True
>>> bool('')
False
```

Answer (score 3):

The only string considered as a `False` value is the empty string. It's how the `__bool__` operation is defined for strings:

```
>>> bool('foobar')
True
>>> bool('False')
True
>>> bool('')
False
```

Answer (score 2):

See python doc on [Boolean operations](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations)

> In the context of Boolean operations, and also when expressions are
>   used by control flow statements, the following values are interpreted
>   as false: False, None, numeric zero of all types, and **empty strings**
>   and containers (including strings, tuples, lists, dictionaries, sets
>   and frozensets). All other values are interpreted as true. (See the
>   `__nonzero__()` special method for a way to change this.)

Answer (score 2):

**Truth Value Testing**

The following values are considered false:

> - None
> - False
> - Zero of any numeric type, for example, 0, 0.0, 0j.
> - any empty sequence, for example, '', (), [].
> - any empty mapping, for example, {}.

From python docs [Truth Value Testing](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)

So `''`, an empty string, returns False.

Answer (score 1):

If `d` is an empty string, it will return `False`, otherwise, if the string has content, it will return `True`.

Answer (score 0):

`1>10` is always false, and thus your code sample doesn't print anything.
While the empty string returns `False`, all other strings are always evaluated to `True`.

Thus

```
d = "some string"
if d:
    print c
```

actually prints `c` since it has evaluated `d` to be `True`